# How to change timezone laravel version 5.4 with specific UTC

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

how do you set your timezone to a specific GMT or UTC in the app.php on your laravel project

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends upon your requirements, Here is the list of supported time zones [Supported Time Zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) Select any region and see the list of zones name.
Eg: I selected America which is [America Time Zone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)

**Eg**: 
Laravel Default timezone is set like this,

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

So you can pass your desire Timezone like this

```
'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
```

Or

```
'timezone' => 'America/Aruba',
```

Comment: Thank you ! problem solved! thanks for that reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)

And edit your **app.php** file:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```